# repeat a Julia iterator indefinitely

Tags: iterator, generator, julia

I'm looking for a way to repeat indefinitely a sequence.
Something comparable to

```
julia> repeat(1:3, outer=2)
9-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 1
 2
 3
```

but with outer being infinite and with result being an iterator (not an Array)

I tried

```
for i in repeatedly([1:3])
    @show i
end
```

with repeatedly for [IterTools](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/IterTools.jl)
but it raises an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On version 0.6 and up, you can use `Base.Iterators.cycle`. For example:

```
julia> using Base.Iterators

julia> collect(take(cycle(1:3),10))
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 1
 2
 3
 1
 2
 3
 1
```

Comment: Thanks about `cycle` maybe ```julia> for i in cycle(1:3)
         @show i
         sleep(1)
       end``` could be a better example

Comment: Sure, it's a good example too. In code which could be pasted by a reader, it is better to have it terminate by itself.

Comment: I don't think you need the inner `collect`

Comment: Thanks Michael K. B. Fixed